# Array that looks like dictionary?

Tags: arrays, swift, swift-dictionary

So I have a plist with a number of items that I would like to access in my project. The plist is an array of items, which are in turn dictionaries with of type string:string (Item1 -> "name" : "somename", "description" : "somedescription")

I would like to access only the name value of my items, and display in an array. I have managed to retreive all the key-value pairs in my plist with the following code:

```
let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "PlistName", ofType: "plist")
let dict = NSArray.init(contentsOf: URL.init(fileURLWithPath: path!)) as! [[String:String]]
```

by using print(dict) I am able to get everything printed to the console, however like I said I only want the names of the items in an array.

What confuses me the most is the fact that the dict is equal to an NSArray of type [[String:String]]. I do not understand how an array can be of type String:String. This looks like a dictionary to me. I tried changing NSArray to NSDictionary, but that gives me an error saying

"Cast from 'NSDictionary?' to unrelated type '[[String : String]]' always fails"

I'm also not able to tap into either the key or value of dict.

Comment: `[String: String]` is a dictionary. `[[String: String]]` is an array of dictionary.

Comment: Ahh that explains a lot, thank you! So what is the easiest way to break this up to end up with an array of just one of the dictionary values?

Answer (score 0):

```
let oneDict = dict[0]
```

returns one dictionary, and if you really want an array of one dictionary do this:

```
let array = [oneDict]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extract values for a specific key by using the `map` or `compactMap` functions, in this case I use `compactMap` in case one of the dictionaries doesn't contain a name

```
let arrayOfDictionaries = [["name": "a", "some": "x"],
                           ["name": "b", "some": "y"],
                           ["some": "z"],
                           ["name": "c"]]

let names = arrayOfDictionaries.compactMap {$0["name"]}
```